# PHP parse string to dateTime() with

Tags: php, datetime

I want to **parse the following string to a DateTime() Object** in PHP:

```
2017-03-03T09:06:41.187
```

I try to do this as follows:

```
$stateCreatedOn = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTH:i:s.u','2017-03-03T09:06:41.187');
var_dump($stateCreatedOn); // -> Returns false
```

However, **parsing doesn´t work** and the variable is always set to false. Anybody an idea **what´s wrong with my date format specification**?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', '2017-03-03T09:06:41.187');
print_r($datetime);
```

prints:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-03-03 09:06:41.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Helsinki
)
```

Comment: Thanks, works great - the escape \ was missing. To also get microseconds: $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', '2017-03-03T09:06:41.187');

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()` function

```
echo strtotime('2017-03-03T09:06:41.187'); // result will be something like 1488517601
```

Comment: `strtotime()` is easiest way to deal with date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

$stateCreatedOn = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u','2017-03-03 09:06:41.187');
var_dump($stateCreatedOn);

Result :
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-03-03 09:06:41.187000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }